# Sql remove Null Values in sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, subquery

I am trying to do sub select queries but i am having Null values in my group by

```
SELECT        convert(varchar, dbo.ArretProductionJournee.DateArret, 3) , 
(select
sum (datediff(minute, ArretProductionJournee.HeureDebut, ArretProductionJournee.HeureFin)  ) 
where ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret Like 'HH')
as HH, 
(select
sum (datediff(minute, ArretProductionJournee.HeureDebut, ArretProductionJournee.HeureFin)  ) 
where ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret Like 'HI')
as HI,
(select
sum (datediff(minute, ArretProductionJournee.HeureDebut, ArretProductionJournee.HeureFin)  ) 
where ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret Like 'PS')
as PS
FROM            
dbo.ArretProductionJournee 
where dbo.ArretProductionJournee.DateArret BETWEEN '01/04/2021'and '03/04/2021'
group by ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret, convert(varchar, dbo.ArretProductionJournee.DateArret, 3)
```

This results like below :

[image]

I want to remove those Null Values to have a result like so :

```
---------------------------
Date Arrêt | HH | HI | PS |
---------------------------
03 / 02/ 21| 0  | 29 | 45 |
```

Comment: GROUP BY ArretProductionJournee.EnumArret alone.

Comment: you can maybe try to use COALESCE

Comment: @jarlh i tried it but ArretProductionJournee.DateArret needs to be in the groupBy for the agregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you do not need those sub-SELECTs. Use conditional aggregation instead. Try this.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DateArret, 3), 
       SUM(IIF(EnumArret Like 'HH', datediff(minute, HeureDebut, HeureFin, 0)) AS HH,
       SUM(IIF(EnumArret Like 'HI', datediff(minute, HeureDebut, HeureFin, 0)) AS HI,
       SUM(IIF(EnumArret Like 'PS', datediff(minute, HeureDebut, HeureFin, 0)) AS PS,
  FROM dbo.ArretProductionJournee 
 WHERE DateArret BETWEEN '01/04/2021'and '03/04/2021'
 GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, DateArret, 3)
```

It's called *conditional aggregation* because each `SUM(IIF(condition, val, 0))` item only adds up rows matching the condition.

I removed the table names from your column names (`ArretProductionJournee.HeureDebut` becomes `HeureDebut`) because you only use one table, and because the query is easier to read that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select convert(date, dbo.ArretProductionJournee.DateArret), 
       sum(case when apj.EnumArret = 'HH'
                then datediff(minute, apj.HeureDebut, apj.HeureFin)  
           end) as HH, 
       sum(case when apj.EnumArret = 'HI'
                then datediff(minute, apj.HeureDebut, apj.HeureFin)  
           end) as HI, 
       sum(case when apj.EnumArret = 'PS'
                then datediff(minute, apj.HeureDebut, apj.HeureFin)  
           end) as PS
from  dbo.ArretProductionJournee apj
where apj.DateArret between '2021-04-01' and '2021-04-03'
group by convert(date, apj.DateArret);
```